# How to navigate to an external URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm creating a simple App in React , using React Router v4, with this structure

```
-Wrapper
 -Home /
 -Homepage /h
    --GalleryContainer  /h/gallery
       ---Gallery  /h/gallery
       ---Item    /h/gallery/:itemId
    --About /h/about
    --Links /h/links
```

in Links, there is a list of elements that redirects to external links. Problem is, when you click on url `www.example.com`, it goes to `http://localhost:7770/h/www.example.com` and render 404 link not found

Here is the code

```
<div className="links">
        <ul>
          {link.links.map((url,i)=>
            <li key={i}><a href={url}>{url}</a></li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

with url being `www.example.com` or any weblink.

How do you make url goes to `www.example.com` and not `http://localhost:7770/h/www.example.com`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add `http://` to the beginning of your url. So your code should be

```
<li key={i}><a href={"http://"+url}>{url}</a></li>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem - with a fixed url. I have http in front of it, but I'm getting the same error as is set out in this question

Comment: Hey, I'm having this same problem on a react application. I want to redirect to eg: 'external_url' but it keeps concating like 'localhost:3000/external_url'